# SQL Query For grouping 7days group

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Hello Developers / Members

I need  help to create sql query as attached photos of table and result. following is detail.

[image: table contain my sql table]

[image: I want to get result]

I tried following code but can't get sucess.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DATEADD(WEEK,0, date_requisition), 105) 
       + ' TO ' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DATEADD(DD, 6, DATEADD(WEEK,0, date_requisition)), 105) cl_Week,
       sum(nu_manpower_used)as "Total CL"
FROM  cl_used
where date_requisition between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-07'
group  by CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DATEADD(WEEK,0, date_requisition), 105) + ' TO ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DATEADD(DD, 6, DATEADD(WEEK,0, date_requisition)), 105)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance. You can also contact me on my email id.

Comment: please use markdown for content, not pictures.

Comment: @FalcoGer  Sir code I mentioned

Comment: Hi @Dharamraj, you need to copy all data into content box like your query.

Comment: Explain the logic *in the question*.  Don't make other people guess on what you are trying to do.